# Css filter blur issue

Tags: javascript, css, filter, blur, perspective

I've tried to create a blurred tiltshift-like focus effect by combining css `perspective` and css `filter:blur(X)` and faced with problem:
 in a small viewport height window something cuts blurred parts with a high blur value and I can't fiured out what is it.
Some help?

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OASWE.png)

[Issue DEMO](http://codepen.io/oneplusuniverse/pen/BpPpKW?editors=0100). Shrink the window to see what i'm talking about.